# C# Magick.Net "no decode delegate for this image format" with SVG

Tags: c#, svg, imagemagick, magick.net

I have ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16 installed and can successfully run `convert test.svg test.pdf` and get a valid pdf output.

In my project I have installed Magick.NET-Q16-x86 version 7.0.0.003 and I can successfully convert other formats using it.

However, when I run the following code, I get an "iisexpress.exe: no decode delegate for this image format" error:

```
using (var image = new MagickImage(File.OpenRead("C:\\Temp\\SvgToPdf\\test.svg"))) //error here
{
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Pdf;
    image.Write("C:\\Temp\\SvgToPdf\\test.pdf");
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crap...wouldn't you know I would figure it out within minutes of posting...this is why I don't ask many questions!

Anyway, for those wondering, the problem was with opening the file using `File.OpenRead` (probably does not have all of the necessary info in the FileStream).  changing my code to this works:

```
using (var image = new MagickImage("C:\\Temp\\SvgToPdf\\test.svg"))
{
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Pdf;
    image.Write("C:\\Temp\\SvgToPdf\\test.pdf");
}
```

Thanks to [dlemstra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410453/dlemstra) for the alternative solution for when you *do* need to use a `Stream`!

```
var readSettings = new MagickReadSettings() { Format = MagickFormat.Svg };
var image = new MagickImage(svgStream, readSettings);
```

Comment: You are correct, ImageMagick cannot detect the svg format from a stream. If you want to use a stream you should also pass a MagickReadSettings instance with the Format property set to MagickFormat.Svg to the MagickImage constructor.

Comment: @dlemstra That is very good to know since I will definitely want to use a stream in the future!

Answer (score 5):

Ufff, I had similar problem.
Magick.NET throws "ImageMagick.**MagickMissingDelegateErrorException**" on creation of **MagickImage** object from Stream with error message like "**no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/CustomStreamToImage/761**".
When I saved the Stream into file, picture is absolutely OK..

... After almost 2 days of debugging/trying I recognized, that this error with the same Stream sometimes throws, sometimes not...
-> the problem is in Stream state. Before MagickImage creation it has to be Seek into beginning!! Maybe this is error in ImageMagick, because... :-/

```
    public ResizedImageWithMetadata GetResizedImageWithMetadata(Stream content,..)
        {
            try
            {
                if (content == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"Image content is empty!");
                }
                using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(content))
                {
// unexpected exception...
```

Correct:

```
public ResizedImageWithMetadata GetResizedImageWithMetadata(Stream content,..)
    {
        try
        {
            if (content == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"Image content is empty!");
            }
            content.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //THIS IS NEEDED!!!
            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(content))
            {
```